# WPF Label.Left Property instead of Margin

Tags: wpf, vb.net

in Windows Form i'm able to specify Left Property of a control, but can anyone help me achieve this in WPF?

```
Label1.Left = 10
```

what i'm trying to achieve:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61853045/textgap.PNG
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61853045/textscrolling.PNG

Comment: What's your problem with margins? They're doing the job.

Comment: i'm trying to move a label using dispatchertimer "Label1.Left = Label1.Left - 1"

Comment: @montolentino You can do that with margin also

Comment: You can use an animation, too.

Comment: i'm trying to animate the text label when the label is too long just like in iOS music app. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
label.Margin = new Thickness(10, 
label.Margin.Top, label.Margin.Right, label.Margin.Bottom);
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. can i use this in XAML? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61853045/textgap.PNG

Comment: but what about determining the Label1.Right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
Label1.Margin= new windows.Thickness(10,0,0,0)
```

Where margin(0) = Left, margin(1) = Top, margin(2) = Right, margin(3) = Bottom